# Laravel 4 Scope Not Working on exact amount

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So my problem is that when the limit in "getAllLikers" is hit it stops and gives me an "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string" error in Laravel 4.2.11. I am using the Likable plugin by rtconner (https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-likeable). It works fine when the amount of likers is below or over the limit, but when it is the exact amount it won't work.

I have tried a lot of different things to try to work around it but I can't seem to make it work. I have also got a friend to look at it and he did not either find a solution.

Do any of you have any suggestions for me? See code below:

Blade Template:

```
<h3 class="text-muted"><small>{{ Model::getLikers($id) }} like this.</small></h3>
```

Model:

```
public function scopeGetLikers($query, $id) {
    $info = DB::table('likeable_likes')->where('likable_type', '=', 'Model')->where('likable_id', '=', $id)->get();
    $totallikes = DB::table('likeable_like_counters')->where('likable_type', '=', 'Model')->where('likable_id', '=', $id)->sum('count');

    if($info == null) {
        return 'No one';
    }

    $person = '';
    $comma = '';
    $int = 0;
    $limit = 1;

    foreach($info as $liker) {

        if($int == 0) {
            $comma = '';
        } else {
            $comma = ', ';
        }

        if($int <= $limit) {
            $person = $person . $comma . User::getUsernameByID($liker->user_id);
        }

        $int++;

    }

    if($int > $limit) {
        return $person . ' and <a href="" id="likes" tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="'. Model::getAllLikers($id) . '">' . ($totallikes - $limit - 1) . ' others </a> ';
    }

    return $person;
}

public function scopeGetAllLikers($query, $id) {
    $info = DB::table('likeable_likes')->where('likable_type', '=', 'Model')->where('likable_id', '=', $id)->get();

    if($info == null) {
        return '9999999';
    }

    $person = '';
    $comma = '';
    $int = 0;
    $limit = 2;

    foreach($info as $liker) {

        if($int = $limit) {
            $comma = '';
        } else {
            $comma = ', ';
        }

        if($int > $limit) {
            $person = $person . $comma . User::getUsernameByID($liker->user_id);
        }

        $int++;

    }

    return $person;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself! :)

So here is the solution:

- Removed the scope "GetAllLikers" because this is where everything went wrong.
- Rewrote the "GetLikers" scope, see code below.

  ```
  public function scopeGetLikers($query, $id) {
  $info = DB::table('likeable_likes')->where('likable_type', '=', 'Model')->where('likable_id', '=', $id)->get();
  $totallikes = DB::table('likeable_like_counters')->where('likable_type', '=', 'Model')->where('likable_id', '=', $id)->sum('count');

  if($info == null) {
      return 'No one';
  }

  $person = '';
  $comma = '';
  $int = 0;
  $limit = 2;
  $persons = array();

  foreach($info as $liker) {
      $persons[] = User::getUsernameByID($liker->user_id);
      $int++;
  }

  if($int < $limit) {
      $limit = $int;
  }

  $arrslice = array_slice($persons, $limit);
  $parr = array_slice($persons, 0, $limit);
  $miniperson = implode(', ', $parr);

  $others = $totallikes - $limit;

  if($int > $limit) {
      return $miniperson . ' and <a href="" id="likes" tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="'. implode(', ', $arrslice) . '">' . $others . ' other' . ($others == 1 ? '' : 's') . ' </a> ';
  }

  return $miniperson;

  }
  ```